# Declaring a sym link in a user's home directory

Tags: nixos

I am managing a shared server, and when I create a user I want to declare a sym link in their home directory to a shared folder that all users can read and write to. I would like to declare this in the configuration.nix file so that setting up a new user is as simple as adding them to file and running nixos-rebuild switch. This seems like a common use case so I'm surprised it doesn't exist, and that makes me think it might not exist for morality reasons (how dare you declare the contents of a user's home directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no NixOS module for that specific use-case, but you can use a oneshot systemd user service to check if the symlink exists and if not create it. One way to do that is with a user activation script:

```
system.userActivationScripts.linktosharedfolder.text = ''
  if [[ ! -h "$HOME/path/to/symlink" ]]; then
    ln -s "$HOME/path/to/symlink" "/path/to/shared/folder"
  fi
'';
```

The script will run each time the user logs in.

Comment: it looks like I also want a `system.activationScript` to setup the shared directory. Thanks!

Comment: `system.userActivationScripts` docs seem to indicate this only happens on a rebuild (although it's not explicit).
`system.activationScripts` mentions that it happens on rebuild and boot. Other sources mention that `system.userActivationScripts` does run on both rebuild and boot so perhaps it's just an omission in the docs.